# Why is my Python code faster than my C code?

Tags: python, c, performance, for-loop, stdout

I recently began learning C, so as a performance test versus python I created the following code to loop through every possible 8 character alphanumeric combination. I noticed the python code ran roughly 20x faster than the C code despite the fact they were mostly the same code. I used PyCharm for the python code and CLion for the C code. Running the .exe file outside of CLion produced the same speed. Here is the code.

Python:

```
char_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
             'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

for char1 in char_list:
    for char2 in char_list:
        for char3 in char_list:
            for char4 in char_list:
                for char5 in char_list:
                    for char6 in char_list:
                        for char7 in char_list:
                            for char8 in char_list:
                                print(char1 + char2 + char3 + char4 + char5 + char6 + char7 + char8)
```

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char charset[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
                      't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < sizeof charset; i1++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < sizeof charset; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < sizeof charset; i3++) {
                for (int i4 = 0; i4 < sizeof charset; i4++) {
                    for (int i5 = 0; i5 < sizeof charset; i5++) {
                        for (int i6 = 0; i6 < sizeof charset; i6++) {
                            for (int i7 = 0; i7 < sizeof charset; i7++) {
                                for (int i8 = 0; i8 < sizeof charset; i8++) {
                                    printf("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\n", charset[i1], charset[i2], charset[i3], charset[i4],
                                           charset[i5], charset[i6], charset[i7], charset[i8]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242201/discussion-on-question-by-jmd123-why-is-my-python-code-faster-than-my-c-code).

Answer (score 1):

Tried it myself, in a console, measuring the time for the first ten million lines:

Python:

```
$ time python3 main.py | head -10000000 | tail
...
real    0m6.075s
user    0m6.246s
sys     0m0.262s
```

C, compiled both ways mentioned in the first answer (now deleted):

```
$ gcc main.c -o main
$ time ./main | head -10000000 | tail
...
real    0m2.140s
user    0m2.350s
sys     0m0.300s
```

```
$ gcc -O3 -Ofast -Og -Os -funroll-loops -s main.c -o main
$ time ./main | head -10000000 | tail
...
real    0m2.119s
user    0m2.278s
sys     0m0.347s
```

My conclusion: Python isn't 20x faster at this but is slower, and what you observed is rather a slow speed of the consoles in which you ran the C program.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I know the issue lies in the method of printing to the consoles because after experimenting without using printing, I found C to be much faster. I'd still like to figure out a way to make printing to the console faster in C. I'll be doing a ton of research on optimization probably.

Comment: @jmd123 don't waste your time trying to make console output faster, it's pointless to have faster console output anyway. The speed here is essentially determined by the speed the console processes output.

Comment: @Jabberwocky damn that's frustrating. I'll try a few more things but I might just give up in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @jmd123 what's the point of having fast console output anyway? Are you going to stare at the console while the program is running? What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I use it whenever I have a program that does something similar to what I just did and creates a ton of data. The console output lets me see it as it is written just so I can see if its doing what I want. It doesn't solve the problem, but lets me see how my code is running stuff.

Comment: @jmd123 Probably the way to make your C program print to the console faster is ... use a faster console. And if you just want to keep an eye on the program's progress, print every millionth line or so.

Comment: `-Og` disables a number of optimisations - why would you use that _and_ enable optimisation - which takes priority?

Comment: @Clifford Not my idea. That's copied from the first answer (now deleted but you have enough reputation to see it), which claimed that compiling like that makes it faster. So I tested exactly that.

Comment: Yes I noted that; the options suggested by Darth-CodeX make little sense IMO. The optimisation for speed vs code size is a often a trade-off, so asking the optimiser to make it both small _and_ fast is likely to end up with something sub-optimal for both - i.e. neither as fast or as small as it could be.  For example loop-unrolling conflicts with code size optimisation.  I would suggest `-O3 -Ofast` - that is apply aggressive optimisation biased toward speed over code size - the optimiser will likely unroll loops without explicitly being told if that is beneficial.

Comment: @Clifford Meh, I already shut the GCE instance down, and it doesn't matter for the point of the question/answer anyway, so I'll probably just keep it as it is. But thanks.

Comment: Agreed - the effect of optimisation is a side issue.

Comment: When running in the time wrapper, it makes little difference.  Somewhat crudely manually timing running for 30 seconds with console output (in a Linux VM running of a Chromebook in my case) unoptimised it gets as far as `aaaare3r` while `-O3 -Ofast` it gets to `aaaazgd7`.  I am surprised that the console output does not obviate any significant optimisation advantage, but clearly not.  Just an observation - no explanation. YMMV

Comment: @Clifford That does sound surprising/interesting, yes.